# define interface method with different parameters in C#

Tags: c#, interface

```
interface parentInterface
{
   public String methodA(/*define parameters name and dataType*/);
}
```

and

```
public class childA : parentInterface
{
  public String methodA(String a, int b, String c, long d){}
}

public class childB : parentInterface
{
   public String methodA(int e, String f, String g){}
}
```

I want to define interface method's parameters name and data type

Comment: This defeates the purpose of an Interface

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're doing, but it sounds like the interface should be generic...

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You could always make `childB`'s the implementation where `childA` calls its version from method a with a default value for `d` but then without knowledge of what methodA actually does, its impossible to tell if this is actually a good idea (i'd imagine it isn't)

Comment: @chole: A lot of people have taken time to offerer you some advice.  It would be respectful to comment on the advice, and upvote anything that is helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two different methods

```
public String methodA(String a, int b, String c, long d){}
```

and

```
public String methodA(int e, String f, String g){}
```

that represent two different contracts to childA and childB respectively.  You cannot define an interface with a single `methodA` that fits both definitions.  What you seek to do is not possible.

Note that you could define both overloads in your interface, but then each class implementing that interface would have to implement both overloads.

Comment: Not only is it not possible, it is fundamentally incorrect. The interface is there is define a contract. What use is this if you cannot tell what parameters a method call takes.

Comment: @DavidPilkington: That's what I meant to express by stating the two different overloads represent two different contracts.

Answer (score 34):

**Make a New Parameter**

This can often be solved by using a `class` or `struct` to use as single parameter rather than the built-in Types.

**The Interface**

You know what to expect from a `class` when it implements a familiar `interface`. We know that all classes implementing the `IEnumerable` interface can be used in a `foreach` loop. By convention, the name of the interface is "I" followed by a description of an ability. It is typical for the name to end with the suffix "-able".

> *-able*  
>   Suffix forming adjectives meaning: 
>             
>   1   -able to be [as in] calculable. 
>             
>   2   -having the quality of [as in] comfortable. 
>   [Oxford English Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=mYicAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA2&dq=%22-able%22%20latin%20suffix%20oxford&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Let's rename `parentInterface` and `MethodA()` to give a clear example of how this normally works (and to avoid negative sanctions):

```
public interface ITreatable
{
    Treatment GetTreatment();
}
```

Well, finding the cure may not be so easy, even if the `object` represents a treatable illness. Here's some examples:

```
public class TheFlu : ITreatable
{
    public Treatment GetTreatment(int year)
    {
        // return some object, Treatment, based on the flu season.
    }
}

public class Hangover : ITreatable
{
    public Treatment GetTreatment()
    {
        return Treatment.Empty; // no parameters necessary.
    }
}

public class Insomnia : ITreatable
{
    public Treatment GetTreatment(FamilyHistory occurances, LabResult lab)
    {
        // return Some Treatment object that can be different based on the
        // calculated risk from the arguments.
    }
}
```

**What We're Really Missing Here**

I don't know biology, but the concept is still the same. You have a group of `ITreatable` illness objects that need to have a `GetTreatment()` method; however, they use different criteria for making calculations. We need `Symptoms`.

```
public class Symptoms
{
    public FamilyHistory History;
    public DateTime Time;
    public LabResult Lab;
    public BloodTest BloodTest;
    public TimeSpan SymptomTime;
    public IsCritical IsCritical;
}
```

Now, the objects can parse the symptoms in their own method, and our interface will look like this:

```
public interface ITreatable
{
    Treatment GetTreatment(Symptoms symptoms);
}
```

Comment: The problem with Symptoms param class is that probably Hangover class will not use most of the properties from it. Maybe a generic class T could be a solution, but also with the generics we can have different problems based on how we implement this generic classes.

Comment: Like, GetTreatment(Symptoms<T> symptoms); ?

Comment: no, like this: `public interface ITreatable<T> { Treatment GetTreatment(T symptoms);} ` but like I said, **it is not without issues this approach**. With a similar problem I've solved with a parameter interface ISymptoms symptoms and a factory method that return the desired implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an interface method with a variable number of arguments using the `params` keyword. But you then need to cast each argument to the appropriate type, which is a bit error prone.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoWork(params object [] arguments);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void DoWork(params object [] arguments)
    {
        string a = (string)arguments[0];
        int b = (int)arguments[1];
        string c = (string)arguments[2];
        long d = (long)arguments[3];

        Console.WriteLine("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}, d={3}", a,b,c,d);
    }
}

public class AnotherFoo : IFoo
{
    public void DoWork(params object [] arguments)
    {       
        int e = (int)arguments[0];
        string f = (string)arguments[1];
        string g = (string)arguments[2];

        Console.WriteLine("e={0}, f={1}, g={2}", e,f,g);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();    
    foo.DoWork("a",1, "c",2L);

    var foo1 = new AnotherFoo();    
    foo1.DoWork(1,"f", "g");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods with different parameters cannot both implement the same interface method declaration. If your method signature does not match that of the interface, you are not implementing the interface.

You can achieve this though, but it is not a good design since the interface is not telling you anything about the method:

```
interface parentInterface
{
    string methodA(params object[] asd);
}


public class childA : parentInterface
{
    public string methodA(params object[] p)
    {
        string a = p[0] as string;
        int b = (int)p[1];
        string c = p[2] as string;
        long d = (long)p[3];
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

public class childB : parentInterface
{
    public string methodA(params object[] p)
    {
        int e = (int)p[0];
        string f = p[1] as string;
        string g = p[2] as string;
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```